# Logging out of Instagram API

Tags: php, jquery, session, instagram, instagram-api

After perusing this site and many others over the last couple days I decided its time to ask my own question.  I am using the Instagram API and want to do a simple user logout.  I am storing a session variable on my side to track when a user is logged in, and destroying when they logout.  After destroying the session (and eventually the Instagram auth token), I have it set to redirect to my homepage where a new user can login.  I have this working fine except for one hiccup.

When I erase my session variable and redirect to the homepage, I can't re-login as another user.  Going to the IG login page just automatically logs in whoever the last user logged in was.

To combat this, I have tried:

- Clearing my cookies
- Opening the IG logout page (instagram.com/accounts/logout) in a new tab, as well as appending it in a hidden img and in a hidden iFrame
- Performing an AJAX call to the logout url

Clearing my cookies does absolutely nothing.

Opening the logout URL in a new tab automatically logs me back in.

Opening a hidden iFrame gives me an error and opening a hidden img does nothing.

Doing an AJAX call is not working due to cross-domain issues.

My Code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#logout", function()   {

    console.log("logout");

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "text",
            data: {token : "-1"},
            url: "http://localhost/Paytag/wp-content/themes/blankslate/set_cookie.php",
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
    });

    $("#account-div").append("<img src='http://instagram.com/accounts/logout/' width='0' height='0' />");

    location.href='http://localhost/Paytag';

})
```

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is painfully obvious.  I had the logout URL wrong all the time.

It VERY SPECIFICALLY has to be this URL:

https://www.instagram.com/logout/

I either didn't include the https://, www or trailing slash, or any combination of the three.  I hope this helped somebody!

Comment: Thanks, when I tried that URL earlier it would redirect me to the logout page, only to automatically log me back in.

Answer (score 0):

logout link for instagram is https://www.instagram.com/accounts/logout/ and it works for me